# Make CSS/Javascript Modal Scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, vertical-scrolling

I'm using the following fiddle to popup my Terms of Service but the content is way too long and goes far past the bottom of the page. I need to make it a certain size and scrollable (Should display on mobile as well): http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

How can I modify this to be a certain size and scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a height and an overflow-y to your modal body

```
.modal-body { height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll }
```